# Google Maps Api changed v3.22

Tags: maps, openlayers, geoserver

Did anyone had problems with Google Maps API? I have a html with openlayers and geoserver. Sincer yesterday, the Google Maps Hybrid map is not working, even if some images are loaded in Firebug. Sometime I receive that google maps api v3.2 is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

same problem for me since monday. Google maps do not want to display maps. I take a look of console and API was deprecated. 
You have to declare the new head in html like this :

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.23&amp">
```

And after download OpenLayers.js
In dev.openlayers.org
For me it's ok, now.

Comment: I use now Bing Maps. :)